# Do I need to migrate shares when migrating AD from windows 2008 r2 DC to 2019 DC?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, migration, shares

I'm migrating a Windows 2008 R2 vm domain controller to 2019, so far after checking the health of the old server, the new server has been promoted to DC, and next step will be to move the fsmo roles. I've seen somewhere though that there is an additional step that not everyone seems to take which is migrate resources (file shares) using something like storage migration service from windows. I'm wondering if this step is necessary as Im not too sure what this step is supposed to do or if I have anything for shares. Is there something that can happen if this is skipped?

Comment: Unless your old DC is used as file server you don't have to migrate any shares.

Comment: If there are user shares (not SYSVOL), then you need to migrate those. If not, then you don't. SYSVOL will replicate automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already commented, you need to migrate any shares that may have been created, excluding the SYSVOL share, which is replicated automatically.

What you maybe heard was about the migration from FRS to DFS-R for the SYSVOL replication. And that is a hard requirement. FSR is not supported on Windows Server 2019 Active Directory Domain Services.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-replication/migrate-sysvol-to-dfsr

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/streamlined-migration-of-frs-to-dfsr-sysvol/ba-p/425405